# multi level parent child sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, hierarchical-data

I have a list of items

- ID             Name         ParentID
- 1              abc             0         (level1)
- 2              def             1
- 3              ghi             1
- 4              jkl             0
- 5              mno             2
- 6              pqr             5
- 7              aaa             1
- 8              vwx             0

I want the list to be sorted as

abc,
aaa,
def,
mno,
ghi,
jkl,
vwx,

that is i want parent (ascending order of name), its children (in ascending order of name), subchildren of children (ascending order of child) and so on till the last level and then again parent.
I have

```
sections = new List<section>( from section in sections
                     group section by section.ParentID into children
                     orderby children.Key
                     from childSection in children.OrderBy(child => child.Name)
                     select childSection);
```

But sorts the list as
abc, jkl, vwx, aaa, def, ghi, mno, pqr

Can anybody let me know where am i going wrong.

Comment: can you just call sections.Sort after the List<section> is populated..otherwise create sections as a sortedlist

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you I will not do this in future

Comment: This is a recursion problem, a couple of days ago a similar question has been asked, and an interesting answer was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438793/720780)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full solution using a stack.  This could definitely be improved on but it's the general algorithm.

```
public class Section
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sections = new List<Section>
            {
                new Section { ID = 1, Name = "abc", ParentID = 0 },
                new Section { ID = 2, Name = "def", ParentID = 1 },
                new Section { ID = 3, Name = "ghi", ParentID = 1 },
                new Section { ID = 4, Name = "jkl", ParentID = 0 },
                new Section { ID = 5, Name = "mno", ParentID = 2 },
                new Section { ID = 6, Name = "pqr", ParentID = 5 },
                new Section { ID = 7, Name = "aaa", ParentID = 1 },
                new Section { ID = 8, Name = "vwx", ParentID = 0 }
            };

        sections = sections.OrderBy(x => x.ParentID).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var stack = new Stack<Section>();

        // Grab all the items without parents
        foreach (var section in sections.Where(x => x.ParentID == default(int)).Reverse())
        {
            stack.Push(section);
            sections.RemoveAt(0);   
        }

        var output = new List<Section>();
        while (stack.Any())
        {
            var currentSection = stack.Pop();

            var children = sections.Where(x => x.ParentID == currentSection.ID).Reverse();

            foreach (var section in children)
            {
                stack.Push(section);
                sections.Remove(section);
            }
            output.Add(currentSection);
        }
        sections = output;
    }
```

Comment: There is no field as level... i just marked to show the root. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oops. That should be `ParentID`

Comment: this gives me the same result as before

Comment: it sorts all the sections with parentID 0 in asc order followed by sections with parent ID 1 and so on... But I need section with parent ID 0 all its children in asc order, all its sub children in asc order and so on until the last level. Again start with the next parent

Comment: Please tell me where am I missing.

Comment: You either need to sort this using recursion or using a stack.  You are essentially traversing a tree.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution.  I am sure that this code could be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

First order by child name and then order group by parent ID, because otherwise with what you have right now the output you're getting is absolutely correct, because once the records have been grouped they are ordered only inside the groupings.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. show me in the code where am i missing