# Sorting the items of a recursive list with "infinite" levels/generations

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this model:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
}
```

This is the query I'm using to load the data into a recursive `<ul>`:

```
List<ProductCategory> DbCategories = _context.ProductCategories
            .ToList().OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
            .Where(e => e.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

That query only apply sorting to the root categories, so I'm adding this to at least sort one generation of children:

```
DbCategories.ForEach(cat => cat.Children = cat.Children.OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).ToList());
```

Now, the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435541/how-do-i-sort-a-list-and-its-children-and-their-children-using-linq/12438793#12438793) suggests adding a method to the class, like this:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();

    public void RecursiveOrder()
    {
        Children = Children.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToList();
        Children.ToList().ForEach(c => c.RecursiveOrder());
    }
}
```

But I'm a bit lost - how would I call such a method?

**Edit** And one more thing; Should the `RecursiveOrder()`-method be in the entity model or the viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the content of your DbCategories.ForEach() call like this:

```
DbCategories.ForEach(cat => cat.RecursiveOrder());
```

You call RecursiveOrder() on first-level children, and it will handle recursively the nested children.

Besides, since it seems that the purpose of this ordering is for UI display, it should be more convenient to put it in the viewmodel (it needs probably to be refactored a little bit in this case)